# VS2019 Hot reload

Tags: visual-studio-2019, blazor-server-side, .net-5

having watched the .Net 5 announcement that VS2019 & Blazor server side now has hot reload (build on save & refresh browser) I find its not working on my VS 2019 or VS2019 preview solution, which was recently upgraded to .Net5.

For example I change some HTML in a view, save, even refresh browser - no update happens.  I have to stop, build & run again.

What are the settings to enable hot reload?

Comment: [Vaporware](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/18486).

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62119532/recompile-razor-files-on-save-for-blazor-wasm) as it might give you some guidance

Comment: thanks Ben, looks like its still a trial & error stage, with launch settings projects & dotnet run watch.

Comment: `dotnet watch run debug`

Answer (score 0):

It's .net 6.0 feature not .net 5 .

1- Update your Visual Studio 2019 to latest version or use vs 2022 preview version.
2- set .net version to 6 in project properties.
3- In package manager console run this command: "dotnet watch"

have fun